# Perl regex for multichar nested bracket

Tags: regex, perl

I use recursive Perl regular reg-expressions to scan for nested singlechar brackets:

```
$RE =     qr'(?:[\(]((?:(?>[^\(\)]+)|(??{$RE}))*)[\)])';
```

This lets me scan c-function calls, something like :

```
"func (a(b()))" ~= /$RE/
```

matching "(a(b()))" . Now I'd like to parse Pascal style nested [if,if-end] brackets, i.e.:

```
if (a) then
   if (b) then
     blaif := 1;
   else 
     blaend := 2;
   end if;
end if;
```

I tried to rewrite $RE from above to:

```
$RE_if  =  qr'(?:(?:if)((?:(?>(?!(?:\bif\b|\bend\s+if))+)|(??{$RE_if}))*)\
(?:\bend\s+if))';
```

But it kindof doesnt work. Does somebody have a regex that handles multichar brackets
like ["if","end if"] ?

-- Greetings Konrad

Comment: `(?!...)+` makes no sense. Should `(?!(?:\bif\b|\bend\s+if))+` be `(?:(?!\bif\b|\bend\s+if).)*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the original pattern: (Extraneous escapes removed. Needless surrounding `(?:)` removed.)

```
[(]                  # Prefix.
(
   (?: (?> [^()] +)  # Some characters containing neither prefix nor suffix.
   |   (??{ $RE })   # Recursion
   )*
)
[)]                  # Suffix.
```

`(?:(?!STRING).)*` is to `STRING` as `[^CHAR]*` is to `CHAR`, so:

```
\bif\b
(
   (?: (?> (?:(?! \b(?:end\s+)?if\b ).)+ )
   |   (??{ $RE })
   )*
)
\bend\s+if\b
```

---

By the way, `(?>PAT+)` can be written `PAT++`.

Comment: @Qtax, Indeed, `(?R)` is more efficient. Can't tell if it's correct, though, since we weren't shown how `$RE` is used. DEFINE-ing a pattern would maybe be better.